# mysql_config_editor for mariadb backups on SUSE

Tags: backup, authentication, mariadb, sles

I want to run an automated backup process for mariadb on SUSE enterprise 12 hosted on Microsoft Azure using mysqlbackup. This requires a mariadb/mysql username and password. I want avoid to hard coding the password in the script which runs the backup process as it is a potential security risk.

The recommended way of doing this is to use command line utility mysql_config_editor to create an encrypted config file (usually ~/.mylogin.cnf) which contains the username and password. You refer to this encrypted config file via parameter --login-path=file of the mysqlbackup command.

The problem is that utility mysql_config_editor is available for Debian/Ubuntu but has not been packaged for SUSE as far as I can see.

Any ideas? Possibilities might be:

1. Find another way of installing mysql_config_editor under SUSE - but I don't really want to compile from source or other such complications - the installation process has to be handed over to someone else later.
2. Run mysql_config_editor on another host (e.g. on Ubuntu) and copy the resulting config file to the target environment. Its not clear to me whether the encryption scheme will work in this case or whether it is tied to the host on which the config file was created.
3. Use some other way of picking up the password.